# _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int') sqflite api store data

Tags: flutter, api, sqflite

What I'm trying to do is...

```
List _loadedPhotos = [];

Future<void> _fetchData() async {
    const apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiUrl));
    final data = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
      _loadedPhotos = data;
    });

    print(data);   
  }
```

Here's the output of print statement...

*Data: [{albumId: 1, id: 1, title: accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt, url: via.placeholder.com/600/92c952, thumbnailUrl: via.placeholder.com/150/92c952}, {albumId: 1, id: 2, title: reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam, url: via.placeholder.com/600/771796, thumbnailUrl: via.placeholder.com/150/771796}...*

This kind of thing

So if I can print a list how do I store that list in a local database?

**I need to store data from api in local database using sqflite.**

I followed a link in geeksforgeeks...

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/persist-data-with-sqlite-in-flutter/

I did the same way...

i.e.

```
Future<int> addPlanets() async {
    List<Planets> planets = _loadedPhotos;
    return await handler.insertPlanets(planets);
  }
```

Then I'm getting an error saying...

**A value of type 'List' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List'.**

After fixing this...

```
Future<int> addPlanets() async {
    List planets = _loadedPhotos;
    return await handler.insertPlanets(planets);
  }
```

There's an exception...

**_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int')**

How to fix this???

Here's my full code...

*model.dart*

```
class Planets {
  late final int albumId;
  late final int id;
  late final String title;
  late final String url;
  late final String thumbnailUrl;

  Planets({
    required this.albumId,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.url,
    required this.thumbnailUrl,
  });

  Planets.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> result)
      : albumId = result["albumId"],
        id = result["id"],
        title = result["title"],
        url = result["url"],
        thumbnailUrl = result["thumbnailUrl"];

  Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    return {
      'albumId': albumId,
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
      'url': url,
      'thumbnailUrl': thumbnailUrl
    };
  }
}
```

*db.dart*

```
class DataBase {
  Future<Database> initializedDB() async {
    String path = await getDatabasesPath();
    return openDatabase(
      join(path, 'planets.db'),
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
        await db.execute('CREATE TABLE planets('
            'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,'
            'albumId INTEGER,'
            'title TEXT,'
            'url TEXT,'
            'thumbnailUrl TEXT,'
            ')');
      },
    );
  }

  Future<int> insertPlanets(List planets) async {
    int result = 0;
    final Database db = await initializedDB();
    for (var planet in planets) {
      result = await db.insert(
        'planets',
        planet.toMap(),
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
      );
    }

    return result;
  }

  Future<List<Planets>> retrievePlanets() async {
    final Database db = await initializedDB();
    final List<Map<String, Object?>> queryResult = await db.query('planets');
    return queryResult.map((e) => Planets.fromMap(e)).toList();
  }
}
```

*gg.dart*

```
class GG extends StatefulWidget {
  const GG({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GG> createState() => _GGState();
}

class _GGState extends State<GG> {
  late DataBase handler;

  List _loadedPhotos = [];

  Future<void> _fetchData() async {
    const apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiUrl));
    final data = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
      _loadedPhotos = data;
    });

    print('Data: $data');
  }

  Future<int> addPlanets() async {
    List planets = _loadedPhotos;
    return await handler.insertPlanets(planets);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    handler = DataBase();
    handler.initializedDB().whenComplete(() async {
      await addPlanets();
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: handler.retrievePlanets(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Planets>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      title: Text(snapshot.data![index].title),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In which steps that I am wrong???

Comment: what output you get from here? `print('Data: $data');`

Comment: Data: [{albumId: 1, id: 1, title: accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt, url: https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952, thumbnailUrl: https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952}, {albumId: 1, id: 2, title: reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam, url: https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796, thumbnailUrl: https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796}...

This kind of thing

Comment: edit? @Yunnosch

Comment: at where you call `_fetchData`?

Comment: I don't. Since I sent data to _loadPhotos list I thought calling _fetchData is not necessary. What should I do?

Comment: you should put `_fetchData` in `initState`, then place `addPlanets` into `_fetchData`.

Comment: You mean like this?

Comment: hmm..like what?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this method with your method

```
Future<int> addPlanets() async {
  await _fetchData();
  List planets = _loadedPhotos;
  return await handler.insertPlanets(planets);
}

Future<int> insertPlanets(List planets) async {
  int result = 0;
  final Database db = await initializedDB();
  for (var element in planets) {
    Planets planets = Planets.fromMap(element);
    result = await db.insert(
      'planets',
      planets.toMap(),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
   );
 }
  return result;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).